# bootstrap-modal two instances

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I was able to load external content to my bootstrap-modal , but every time i call the modal page it creates an extra instance, see this screenshot
user (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67763500/modal%20issue.PNG)
how to troubleshoot this? I believe it's on the CSS, but not sure where exactly.

here are my views code:

```
<div id="responsive" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="760" style="display: none;">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Info</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">

    @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>*@
</div>
```

Click me !

and here is the code for the target modal

```
<div class="modal-body">
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayName("User Name")
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @ViewBag.username
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name_Prefix)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name_Prefix) .
    </dd>

</dl>

<p>
    @*@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.CustomerId }) |*@
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was another script on my page that caused the issue.
I removed it and it works like a charm.